# Её самооценка спущена/спущенна

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Её мнение о себе занижено/заниженно.

> Её самооценка спущена/спущенна.

Comment: До Дня Смеха вроде далеко...

Comment: Его заниженное мнение упиралось в его спущенную самооценку.